# Wine won't open any programs

Tags: macos, wine

Running macOS Sierra(Version 10.12.2 16C67).

I installed [Wine](https://www.winehq.org) version `wine-1.8.6` (through a .pkg file). I opened up a game and it worked fine.

The next day when I downloaded Origin installer, it wouldn't open. When I double clicked on it, the Wine icon showed up in the dock and said it was open, but no windows showed up. When I clicked on another program(or on the desktop), Wine closed. Now when I try to start that same game I opened when I first installed Wine, the same thing happens that happened when I started Origin installer.

When I go to the terminal and type `wine {path of .exe}` I got this:
[image]

I installed wine tricks using `brew install winetricks` and it installed fine, yet it didn't change my situation.

`winecfg` works properly, and so does `sh winetricks`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real problem was that I had removed the `Z:` drive which pointed to my root directory. After adding the `Z:` drive back using `winecfg`, I was able to run Windows programs from any location again.

[image: image showing Z: drive pointing to root directory in winecfg]

Answer (score 2):

You can consider installing *Wine.app* via brew-cask, e.g.

```
brew cask install wine-stable
```

By using the macOS app, it can handle executable and file locations in a better way.

There is also the [WineBottler app](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) which comes with *Wine.app* as well.